# Node relationships in a network?

Tags: sql, excel

I have two columns A and B, which contain IDs for different organizations and different funds, respectively. Column A has 1,200 distinct values (distinct organizations) with repeats. Column B has about 350 distinct values (distinct funds) with repeats. There are about 8,500 separate rows, each distinct, since they represent grants made from a fund to an organization.

Thing is, multiple funds make grants to the same organization, so that these funds are essentially 'connected' to each other through grant making.

I want to find 1) The NUMBER of other funds a fund is related to through grant making and 2) WHICH funds have the most connections with each other.

Does this make sense? If so, how do you go about solving for these values? I extracted the data in SQL Server and have tried using the R sna package, NodeXL, and some nested Excel functions to no avail. I'm out of my element.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If I'm reading this right, you just want to write a query that finds funds in column A that are also in column B?

Comment: Not quite. For example, in Column A I have a list of twenty instances of Organization 12, which represents twelve different grants. In Column B I have a list of 12 different funds which made those grants. I want to find instances when combinations of those 12 funds occurred together again for a different organization. Does that make sense? *Edit. Yes, I've got measures of Betweenness Centrality and In Degree/Out Degree for the columns.

Comment: If you tried so many different things, it would help if you posted what you have tried, including the code for those R scripts, or the xls functions. That makes it easier to help you.

Comment: Sure, here's the SQL statement:                                'SELECT ORG_ID, FUND_ID
, COUNT(*) AS CNT
FROM dbo.ORGS
INNER JOIN FUND ON FUND.GRNT_ID = ORGS.GRNT_ID
WHERE ORG.ORG_ID = '1001'                                    GROUP BY ORG.ORG_ID, FUND.FUND_ID)'

Comment: Now that I have the values which show how many distinct funds gave to any individual organization, how do I compare across organizations to determine which funds gave to the same organization X amount of times...Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question right, this is what you need.

```
select  b.fund, COUNT(*)
from yourtable a inner join yourtable b on a.org = b.org 
group by b.fund order by COUNT(*) desc
```

this will return the identities of funds that they are associated with (NOTE: it will count things twice, for example if (org1, fund1) and (org2, fund1) and (org1, fund2) exists, it will return (fund1, 3), (fund2, 3) becuase there are three fund relationships associated with the organization that is associated with fund1 and fund2.

if you want to only count DISTINCT funds involved in this relationship use:

```
select  b.fund, COUNT(distinct a.fund)
from yourtable a inner join yourtable b on a.org = b.org 
group by b.fund order by COUNT(distinct a.fund) desc
```

note that this will count itself.

both of these will automatically order them with the highest number of associated funds on top.

**EDIT:**
Upon learning more about the question and the table structure, I think this works:

```
    select f1.fund_ID, f2.fund_ID, Count(distinct o1.org_ID) 
from Fund f1 inner join orgs o1 on o1.grnt_id = f1.grnt_id 
inner join orgs o2 on o1.org_ID = o2.org_id and o1.grnt_id <> o2.grnt_id 
inner join fund f2 on f2.grnt_id = o2.grnt_id and f2.fund_id <> f1.fund_Id 
where f1.FUND_ID < f2.FUND_ID
group by f1.fund_ID, f2.fund_ID order by count(o1.org_ID) desc
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Here's the code I used, similar to yours.                                                        `SELECT ORG_ID, FUND_ID
, COUNT(*) AS CNT
FROM dbo.ORGS
INNER JOIN FUND ON FUND.GRNT_ID = ORGS.GRNT_ID
WHERE ORG.ORG_ID = '1001'... OR WHERE ORG.ORG_ID = '9999'                                        GROUP BY ORG.ORG_ID, FUND.FUND_ID)`                                      I have a table that shows distinct funds and the number of times they gave to any one organization. Now, though, I'm wondering how many times different sets of funds gave to the same organization...?

Comment: so you need to see ORG, [# of funds that gave to ORG]? if so you should be able to `select ORG_ID, COUNT(distinct fund.fund_ID) as CNT from dbo.ORGS INNER JOIN FUND ON FUND.GRNT_ID = ORGS.GRNT_ID group by ORG_ID order by Count(distinct fund.fund_ID) desc`

Comment: to see how many times a fund gave to an organization : `select ORG_ID, FUND.FUND_ID, COUNT(*) as CNT from dbo.ORGS INNER JOIN FUND ON FUND.GRNT_ID = ORGS.GRNT_ID group by ORG_ID, Fund.Fund_ID order by Count(FUND.GRNT_ID) desc`

Comment: Yes, that's right. Now I have ORGs, distinct FUNDs, and the number of times each fund gave to that org as CNT. Is there a way to compare across organizations in SQL to determine how many times two or more funds share the same grantee?

Comment: so do you want (FUND1, FUND2, #of orgs they have in common?)

Comment: Yessir. Ideally, though, I would want to be able to do this with many combinations of funds. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: This might be a bit difficult since your org table isn't normalized, but I think this will work for you. `select f1.fund_ID, f2.fund_ID, Count(distinct o1.org_ID) from Fund f1 inner join org o1 on o1.grnt_id = f1.grnt_id inner join org o2 on o1.org_ID = o2.org_id and o1.grnt_id <> o2.grnt_id inner join fund f2 on f2.grnt_id = o2.grnt_id and f2.fund_id <> f1.fund_Id group by f1.fund_ID, f2.fund_ID order by count(o1.org_ID) desc `

Comment: and just to help out, you may want to create a "grant" table (known as a linker table for many to many relationships like this) with columns fund_ID, ORG_ID. that way, you only need 1 org row and 1 fund row per organization and fund.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this now. Will report back with results. :)

Comment: Am a little confused--why are there 3 inner joins if there are only 2 tables in play?

Comment: the joins are fund > org > org > fund, this way we get 2 non-identical funds joined with 2 non-identical GRANTS that are part of the same org.

Comment: If my understanding of your table structure is correct 'ORGS(ORG_ID,GRNT_ID) and FUND(FUND_ID,GRNT_ID)'

Comment: Yes, that structure is correct. Still plugging away over here, since I haven't been able to test it out yet.

Comment: Thanks, Subliminy! Really appreciate your help.